# android: after closing the app its still running

Tags: android, webview

I am using `webview`, and I'm appending some query string with the URL. Say URL is `file:///android_asset/www/index.html` and I have added the query string `?urlid=MindTree_Projects&city=bangalore&firstTimeRule=%7B%22EEI....something`. So the whole URL looks like `file:///android_asset/www/index.html?urlid=MindTree_Projects&city=bangalore&firstTimeRule=%7B%22EEI....something`. Now suppose I open the app and then close it, still its running, but in foreground its closed.

Only I can see it running in `chrome://inspect`. Which is one of the way to debug web apps.

Can any body tell me why this is happening, it worth for me.

Comment: Normally, you (i.e. the user) don't "close" an app. You basically only ever switch to another app, which may also be the home screen. The Android OS then decides when it's time to actually terminate your app, which means that your app may be running for hours in the background. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html and consider momo's answer too.

Comment: It's so **by design**. Not only **your** app is behaving like that. **All** are. And **on iOS, too**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to call the methods `onPause()` and `onResume()` of the [WebView Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause(); // pauses the WebView (JavaScript, flash etc.)
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.onResume(); // resumes the WebView (JavaScript, flash etc.)

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    relativeLayoutPlaceholder.removeView(mWebView); // removes the WebView from its Placeholder
    mWebView.destroy(); // destroys the WebView
    mWebView = null;
}
```